# VirtualBox running Ubuntu 14.04, after update and reboot can't change size and other problems

Tags: 14.04, boot, virtualbox, update-manager

After updating my Ubuntu virtualbox, I have encountered several problems:

1. the copy-paste buffer is not the same from my host machine to the Ubuntu machine.
2. I can't access shared drives
3. I can't download virtualbox-guest packages. When I do , I get the following error:

`The following package may have unmet dependencies:
virtualbox-guest-x11 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11
                            Depends: xerver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.10.99.901)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update guest additions in the VM. If your guest is running ubuntu:

> sudo /media/$user/$vboxversion/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run

Comment: what goes in $vboxversion ? Is it the Ubuntu OS version?

Comment: Do a `ls /media/user`. For example: `ls /media/steve` produces `VBOXADDITIONS_4.3.20_96996`.